# WampServer Hosts file not exit

Tags: wampserver

There is a problem with my wamp server after i install it. However, my wamp server still as normal but may i know how to correct this errors?

errors as below:

> The file: C:/WINDOWS/system32/drivers/etc/hosts is not writable
>
> The file C:/WINDOWS/system32/drivers/etc/hosts does not exists

[image: Screen Shot]

May i know how to correct it ?

Comment: You probably have a Firewall that is protecting the HOSTS file, lots do nowadays. Go to your Firewall and set an exception for wampserver, or just remove the HOSTS file from the Firewall's protection temporarily, that is also possible with most firewalls that protect the hosts file

Comment: Oh just for reference, the HOSTS file belongs to Windows and it not part of WAMPServer

Comment: Thanks for your answer,may i know how to set the exception for wampserver or remove the HOSTS file from firewall protection?

Comment: For now i am using this to create a HOSTS file for me and the error have been slove but is it a correct way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Check this `C:/WINDOWS/system32/drivers/etc` path, your hosts file is probably missing. Just follow these steps to fix the problem.

1. Create new text file on desktop and rename it to "hosts". Don't add extension.
2. Open it with any text editor, paste the following code and save it.

```
    # Copyright (c) 1993-2006 Microsoft Corp.
    #
    # This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
    #
    # This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
    # entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
    # be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
    # The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
    # space.
    #
    # Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
    # lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
    #
    # For example:
    #
    #      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
    #       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host
    # localhost name resolution is handle within DNS itself.
    #       127.0.0.1       localhost
    #       ::1             localhost
```

3. Now move the file to `C:/WINDOWS/system32/drivers/etc` folder.
4. Exit `WAMP` if its running and start it again. The error will be gone.

for more detail checkout Microsoft support article here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/972034/how-to-reset-the-hosts-file-back-to-the-default