# My .php files not running on WAMP Server, it is trying to save the file instead

Tags: php, apache, wamp

I have just cloned a project, so it works perfectly fine when i load it e.g: "localhost/example/contact.html", but when i click to homepage which the endpoint is "localhost/example/index.php" it asks me to save the file like that:
[Asking to save the php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afq10.png)

I have checked everything in files such as php.ini, httpd.conf but still cant find a solution, I also reinstalled wamp 2 times.

Also the php error log gives me this error: The file C:/WINDOWS/system32/drivers/etc/hosts does not exists

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WampServer Hosts file not exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53587463/wampserver-hosts-file-not-exit)

Comment: I have hosts and everything, but error still appears, so I dont think the host file is the problem for the .php file saving :/

Comment: I know it's not necessarily the best thing to do, but have you tried running WAMP as an administrator? PHP not starting is the reason why your .php file is being downloaded.

Comment: No I am running WAMP always as admin

Answer (score 1):

You need to load and enable mod_php or set up php-fpm. Afaik Wamp uses mod_php which is simpler. The reason your web browser asks you to download the php files is because you have not told the web server to treat .php files differently that .txt files.

There are plenty of resources on the interwebs about setting up php and apache:

- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/PHP

Given that you are using Wamp, which should work out of the box, I'd say reinstall one more time and run the installer as an admin. If the issue about the etc/hosts file persists, [you can create the file yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53587463/wampserver-hosts-file-not-exit).

However, I don't think the hosts file is necessary to run wamp or to render / run .php files.

---

PS: Your question is not about programming or code, so it's going to be closed because it fits better on the superuser website. Welcome to SO!